# Convert Arabic numbers in a Pandas column to integers

Tags: python, pandas

I have been given a survey for analysis. Unfortunately, some of the participants have used Arabic/Farsi numbers to fill some values. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(["24", "۱۲", "45", "۳۲"], columns=["age"])
```

and what I want is to convert all the values to Python integers:

```
[24, 12, 45, 32]
```

What is the most canonical/performant way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `unidecode` first through your numbers, and then convert using `pd.to_numeric`

```
pip install unidecode
from unidecode import unidecode

df['numbers'] = pd.to_numeric(df.age.apply(unidecode), errors='coerce')
```

---

```
  age  numbers
0  24       24
1  ۱۲       12
2  45       45
3  ۳۲       32
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `apply` Python's built-in `int` function which does understand Arabic numerals:

```
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> df = DataFrame(["24", "۱۲", "45", "۳۲"], columns=["age"])
>>> df['age'] = df['age'].apply(int)
>>> df['age']
0    24
1    12
2    45
3    32
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

Actually, `numpy`/`pandas` dtypes are also aware of Unicode numerals. So usual type castings also work:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Series(["24", "۱۲", "45", "۳۲"], dtype='float64')
0    24.0
1    12.0
2    45.0
3    32.0
dtype: float64
>>> pd.Series(["24", "۱۲", "45", "۳۲"]).astype('int64')
0    24
1    12
2    45
3    32
dtype: int64
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(["24", "۱۲", "45", "۳۲"], dtype='int64')
array([24, 12, 45, 32], dtype=int64)
>> np.array(["24", "۱۲", "45", "۳۲"]).astype('float16')
array([24., 12., 45., 32.], dtype=float16)
```